# how to change the size(width/height) of a textarea or a text which is readonly dynamically?

Tags: jquery, django, textarea

I have a django model, which includes several readonly textareas and texts. for example:

```
class FormTask(forms.Form):
     name = forms.CharField(required = False, max_length = 300, 
                widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {"readonly" : "readonly"}),
                label = "task name")
     id = forms.CharField(required = False, max_length = 300, 
                widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {"readonly" : "readonly"}),
                label = "task ID")
     script = forms.CharField(required = False, max_length = 2000, 
                widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {"readonly" : "readonly"}),
                label = "task script")
```

I find the textarea(script) could not be filled with the commands when I render the model into a html page by using jquery, and this textarea is readonly, so I want to change its size dynamically. could you tell me what should I do if I want to change its size, please? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#textareaID").width(123);// by this 123 px width set
$("#textareaID").height(123);// by this 123 px height set
```

reference

[height](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

[width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: I want to get the size dynamically, for example, the size for the textarea is 100 * 100 while I get a script command whose length is 150. and the size would be 100 * 300 while the length of the script command is 400. thank you!

Comment: if you get 100 * 300 then split by var ab=split("*") then use  $("#textareaID").width(ab[0]);$("#textareaID").height(ab[1]);